# Python Mouse click simulate halts program until you press CTRL+C

Tags: python, mouse, interrupt, auto, simulate

I'm just trying to simulate a mouse click every second but once the first click starts, the program just completely halts and I have no idea why

The program will continue if I press CTRL+C but then it halts again after it clicks:

```
import pyautogui
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Clicking")
    pyautogui.click()
```

And it doesn't matter which mouse library I use to simulate the click, it **always halts**. It should be clicking every second without interruption. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason i think it does so is because it clicks at some place where it is not supposed to(by default the position is your current mouse pointer), so the `pyautogui.click()` takes 2 parameters x,y try specifying the the exact coordinate and it should work. To find the coordinates of a position place your mouse pointer there and run `pyautogui.position()`.